# Antibiotics, Strep and Taanit Esther

Tags: halacha, medicine, purim, fast-days

Can someone with a bacterial infection, such as strep throat, but can not swallow the antibiotics dry or with minimal water, take the medicine using a full glass of water and/or dissolving the antibiotic in it?

I am pretty sure that the antibiotic itself is allowed, since it is medically necessary, and  since Taanit Esther tends to be lenient, I imagine that this might be fine, but I wanted to know if anyone could clarify.

Tangentially, does such an illness fall into a 'choleh she-ein bo sakana'... especially as it can be more dangerous if left untreated? If so, does that mean there is the option to eat outside of the antibiotics if feeling weak?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: Though you should consult your LOR, you can also read http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tanit_Ester#cite_note-15 so when you discuss it, you understand some opinions.

Comment: I'd ask my LOR, but I can't get in touch with him right now :) Figured this could give me a baseline since I see a lot of smart people with sources in other answers... I've checked this site numerous times but this is a first time in needing an answer!

I've edited it to make it more general; hope that's acceptable.

Comment: check out the section on exemptions http://vbm-torah.org/archive/moadim69/20-69moed.htm